Benefits of recording audio directly into Zoom H1n as opposed to using as a pre-amp and recording into camera
My current camera setup includes a Sony a6400, a Rode VideoMic Pro+ and a Zoom H1n. This gives me a couple options for sound recording:

Rode records into Zoom, sync audio in post
Rode runs through Zoom to use the Zoom's pre-amps, then records into camera

Is option 1 going to give me significantly better sound quality? And for solo shooting or a barebones crew is it worth the hassle of dealing with two recording devices?


Is option 1 going to give me significantly better sound quality?

No.

And for solo shooting or a barebones crew is it worth the hassle of dealing with two recording devices?

It depends on whether you consider “bare bones” to include a boom op. IMHO a dedicated boom operator is a must for getting professional quality location dialog recorded. If you have a boom op, then they can double as location sound mixer and it’s very often more convenient on location for them to record to a portable device that they wear instead of having to run cables or wireless between boom and camera.
These days wireless rigs can be very good sounding so that may be an option (boom mic to mixer to wireless transmitter to camera for recording with video).
Another reason to have a dedicated recorder is if your camera only records stereo and you want more than two separate tracks of audio. One boom plus two lavs is already three tracks, and that’s a great way to get location dialog with solid post production choices available.
All of this is from the point of view of scripted fiction or docudrama production. For documentaries or journalism, you don’t need the same kind of verisimilitude that is ideal for fiction, so you can go without a boom op and just record right to the camera.

Thanks! Another thought, the Zoom records 24 bit audio and the camera is 16 bit audio. Does that change anything?
